# You didn't pass an authentication token in java

Tags: java, api, authentication

I am wanting to use the POST method. I have an API where I want POST using HttpConnection. But It not working. It shows "You didn't pass an authentication token. Learn how to authenticate and get your API token here: [https://replicate.com/docs/reference/http#authentication"](https://replicate.com/docs/reference/http#authentication%22)

My code is

```
try {
            String apiUrl = "https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions";
            String apiToken = "****************";

            // Construct the JSON payload
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("version", "494ca4d578293b4b93945115601b6a38190519da18467556ca223d219c3af9f9");

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\ruhul\\OneDrive\\ছবিগুলি\\ads.PNG");
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);

            jsonObj.put("model", "Image Denoising");
            jsonObj.put("image", fileBody);
            json.put("input", jsonObj);

            String message = json.toString();


            // Create the HTTP connection
            URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token " +  apiToken);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            // Send the JSON payload
            OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            // Get the response
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(responseCode);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();

            // Print the response
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

What I can do now?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think there's nothing wrong with the Java code itself. I don't know why you're getting the authentication error, for me it's 422 'unprocessable' (I used some random picture I had on HDD), meaning there's some problems with JSON input.

In the documentation you posted the first example is to send `text: Alicia` as the input, and when you change your code to contain this text instead of file contents, it works with 201 returned.

Maybe try and go the curl route first to make sure it works and then code it, but generally, the code to open connection and make a http request works.

Comment: Was you trying with the same code. Which I had posted?

Comment: Yes, just regular ctrl+c/ctrl+v into my `public static void main`. I didn't notice the API key was there at first, so I did make two calls with it, sorry.

Comment: @RmTomal still have the reply in my IntelliJ Run window:
201
{"id":"nm6bgashpvdgrjd6ikz353k5xq","version":"5c7d5dc6dd8bf75c1acaa8565735e7986bc5b66206b55cca93cb72c9bf15ccaa","input":{"text":"Alicia"},"logs":"","error":null,"status":"starting","created_at":"2023-05-27T21:54:01.632538037Z","urls":{"cancel":"https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions/nm6bgashpvdgrjd6ikz353k5xq/cancel","get":"https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions/nm6bgashpvdgrjd6ikz353k5xq"}}

Comment: I see your request in my API console. I don't understand where is the problem

Comment: One thing is, I used code from their documentation which is `5c7d5dc6dd8bf75c1acaa8565735e7986bc5b66206b55cca93cb72c9bf15ccaa` instead of yours. I don't know what it is, just decided to follow documentation blindly. But this should have no meaning, since the error definitely shows behaviour of missing token, same as if you just open the 'cancel' link from my previous comment and try opening it in the browser.